# How to test a set of conditions on a large number of variants in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements, permutation

In Python, I have a lot of possible permutations of which only one is valid (True).
The permutations are generated by code similarly like the code below.

My question: can this be done faster ? How ?

```
from itertools import permutations, product
from datetime import datetime

def variant_generator(act, prop):
    for this_permutation in product(permutations(range(act)), repeat=prop):
        yield this_permutation

def is_valid_permutation(this_variant):
    if this_variant[1][3] == this_variant[2][2]:
        if this_variant[0][0] == this_variant[1].index(3):
            if this_variant[1][4] == 0:
                if this_variant[2][0] == 4:
                    if this_variant[0][4] == this_variant[2][4]:
                        if this_variant[0][1] == 1:
                            # ... condition(n-1) ...
                            # ... condition(n) ... enough to result in ONE variant
                            return True

timerstart = datetime.now()

variants = variant_generator(6, 3)
for this_variant in variants:
    if is_valid_permutation(this_variant):
        print('valid: ', this_variant)

timerend = datetime.now()
print('it took: {} seconds'.format((timerend-timerstart).seconds))
```

Comment: `all(list of lambdas applied)` might do something for you

Comment: What you are looking to do is a brute force cracker? What are you trying to optimize? Generating the permutations?

Comment: Your 'for loop' on *variants* will execute 373,248,000 times. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: How long does your implementation run for?

Comment: @Ironkey 
I know of the power of lambda statements, however I cannot apply it to this task. Can you elaborate, preferably with actual code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer to speed up

I just wanted to point out that below is equivalent code, you can reduce depth of indentation. If above was intentional, then I can delete my answer

```py
from itertools import permutations, product
from datetime import datetime

def variant_generator(act, prop):
    for this_permutation in product(permutations(range(act)), repeat=prop):
        yield this_permutation

def is_valid_permutation(this_variant):
    if this_variant[1][3] != this_variant[2][2]:
        return False
    if this_variant[0][0] != this_variant[1].index(3):
        return False
    if this_variant[1][4] != 0:
        return False
    if this_variant[2][0] != 4:
        return False
    if this_variant[0][4] != this_variant[2][4]:
        return False
    if this_variant[0][1] != 1:
        return False
    # ... condition(n-1) ...
    # ... condition(n) ... enough to result in ONE variant
    return True

timerstart = datetime.now()

variants = variant_generator(6, 3)
for this_variant in variants:
    if is_valid_permutation(this_variant):
        print('valid: ', this_variant)

timerend = datetime.now()
print('it took: {} seconds'.format((timerend-timerstart).seconds))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that utilises multiprocessing. On my system this runs significantly faster than the code in question. Results will vary per platform. The value of BLOCK will affect performance in different ways per platform. The value shown here appears to be optimal on my machine. My total execution time is ~120s

```
from itertools import permutations, product
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp


def variant_generator(act, prop):
    for this_permutation in product(permutations(range(act)), repeat=prop):
        yield this_permutation


def ivp(v):
    vr = []
    for this_variant in v:
        if this_variant[1][3] == this_variant[2][2]:
            if this_variant[0][0] == this_variant[1].index(3):
                if this_variant[1][4] == 0:
                    if this_variant[2][0] == 4:
                        if this_variant[0][4] == this_variant[2][4]:
                            if this_variant[0][1] == 1:
                                # ... condition(n-1) ...
                                # ... condition(n) ... enough to result in ONE variant
                                vr.append(f'{str(this_variant)} is valid')
    return vr


def getresults(results):
    for r in results:
        for _r in r.get():
            print(_r)


def main():
    timerstart = datetime.now()
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        variants = variant_generator(6, 3)
        BLOCK = 100_000
        V = [None] * BLOCK
        results = []
        i = 0
        for this_variant in variants:
            V[i] = this_variant
            if (i := i + 1) % BLOCK == 0:
                results.append(pool.apply_async(ivp, [V]))
                i = 0
        results.append(pool.apply_async(ivp, [V[:i]]))
        getresults(results)

    timerend = datetime.now()
    print(f'Duration: {timerend - timerstart}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution with 'Yield' by returning a solution which checks for a condition, and if True, passes it to the next condition, one by one. This saves memory and speed, because at any given moment in time, one solution is considered.

In pseudocode:

```
subroutine_to_check_for_clue_1 (candidates):
    for each candidate in candidates:
        if the clue applies to this candidate:
            yield this candidate

subroutine_to_check_for_clue_n-1 (candidates):
    for each candidate in candidates:
        if the clue applies to this candidate:
            yield this candidate

subroutine_to_check_for_clue_n (candidates):
    for each candidate in candidates:
        if the clue applies to this candidate:
            yield this candidate

main routine:
    candidate_generator:
        solutions = (subroutine_n(subroutine_n-1(subroutine_... (subroutine_1(candidate))))
```